# Hide textbox based on its value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, textbox

I've got a canvas on which I can add text and image layers, below the canvas I have a couple of textboxes in which I display information about the selected layer. The things I display are:

- X coördinate
- Y coördinate
- Width
- Height
- Font
- Font Size
- Font Color
- Titel
- Angle

Now since an image layer does not have a Font, Font Size and Font Color it will display 'undefined' now.

I am using this javascript code to display the info in the textboxes:

```
document.getElementById('width').value = Math.round(layer.width*100)/100;
document.getElementById('height').value = Math.round(layer.height*100)/100;
document.getElementById('x').value = layer.offsetX;
document.getElementById('y').value = layer.offsetY;
document.getElementById('color').value = layer.fontColor;
document.getElementById('color').style.color=layer.fontColor;
document.getElementById('font').value = layer.fontFamily;
document.getElementById('size').value = layer.fontSize;
document.getElementById('title').value = layer.title;
document.getElementById('angle').value = Math.round(layer.angle*100)/100;
```

**The question:**
Is there any way to hide the textboxes disappear when they contain the word 'undefined'?
Also will it be possible to hide the plain text in front of the boxes? (Font:, Size:, Color)

A working version of the canvas can be found in [this codepen!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/krzLn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a helper function that hides or shows the element depending on the value === undefined or not:

```
function setElementValueById(id, value){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if(element != null){
        element.style.display = value !== undefined ? '': 'none';
        element.value = value;
    }
}

// usage 
setElementValueById('font', layer.fontFamily);
```

### Edit:

To hide the label also, you can group each box and its label inside a single element (div):

(based on your codepen  example)

```
<td>
X:
<input id="x" type="number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" size="5">
Y:
<input id="y" type="number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" size="5">
```

becomes:

```
<td>
 <div>X:
      <input id="x" type="number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" size="5">
 </div>
 <div>Y:
      <input id="y" type="number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" size="5">
 </div>
```

Then modify the function to show/hide the parent div:

```
// Searches for the element with the given id and sets its value.
// If the value is strictly equal to 'undefined',
// the element's parent will be hidden.
function setElementValueById(id, value){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if(element != null){
        element.parentElement.style.display = value !== undefined ? '': 'none';
        element.value = value;
    }
}

// usage 
setElementValueById('font', layer.fontFamily);
```

Comment: Thnx, this works great. However I did forget something in my question, is it also possible to hide the plain text in front of the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution:

```
var value = // get the value from layer
if(typeof value === 'undefined') {
    // hide the box
}
```

Since it looks like you are not using jQuery, it will be harder for you to hide the input:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
```

And show:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
```

With jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(id).show();
```

Respectively:

```
$(id).hide();
```